# ZeroMQ.js: With zmq.Pair, if socket.send() is called outside of an async loop, then the messages will not not received by the receiver

Tags: javascript, node.js, zeromq, messaging

My setup

- macOS 10.15.7
- zeromq.js: v6.0.0-beta.6
- node.js: v14.4.0

I'm using ZeroMQ.js to communicate between my app's frontend and backend.

The pattern in use is `zmq.Pair`. And the client, a.k.a. the frontend, can receive messages from the server, a.k.a. the backend, just fine.

### Code

```js
class UiBridge {
    constructor(address="tcp://127.0.0.1:25555") {
        this.address = address;
        this.socket = new zmq.Pair();
    }

    async Start() {
        await this.socket.connect(this.address);

        console.log("frontend: Connected to backend.");

        const listen = async () => {
            for await (const [backendRequest] of this.socket) {
              switch (backendRequest.toString()) {
                case 'msg1':
                  onMsg1();

                  // THIS Send works!
                  // the receiver gets the reply.

                  this.Send("reply");
                  break;

                case 'term':
                  this.Stop();
                  break;

                default:
                  console.error(`undefined message from backend: ${backendRequest}`);
              }
            }
        }
      
        listen();
    }
    
    async Stop() {
        if (!this.socket.closed) {
          this.socket.close()
        }
    }

    async Send(cmd) {
        try {
            await this.socket.send(cmd);
            alert(`sent msg: ${msg}`);
        } catch (err) {
            alert(`send failed due to : ${err}`);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if I send message inside the listening loop on receiving any message from the other side, then the send works.

### Problem

But if I send messages outside of this listening loop anywhere else in the frontend code, then the other end never receives the sent message, and no exceptions are caught. Like in a button callback

```js
function onToggleButton() {

    // This is never received!

    gUiBridge.Send("from frontend");
}
```

The button callback is triggered and I see the alert coming up. I've made sure that I can already receive messages from the server before clicking on buttons.

### Workaround

I had to create another pair of PUSH/PULL to send messages from anywhere of my frontend to backend, so that I'm not blocked by this issue. But this is suboptimal.

### Question

Is this by design or am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Do you see the alert on button click?

Comment: @anttud Yes I do.

Comment: has `Start` been called when you are trying the external call to `Send` ?

Comment: @Matt yes. I've made sure that I can already receive messages from the server before clicking buttons.